# asp.net core 1.0 SQL Server connection string for production environment?

Tags: asp.net

I am having a difficult time setting up a connection string to an Azure SQL database in a production environment.

I am trying to use system variables instead of the json/xml files.

`var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables("environment_variable_name");
            var config = builder.Build();
            Services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("environment_variable_name")));`

But that does not seem to be getting the value out of the environment variable.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

When debugging, I see the config variable gets populated with the right key/value, however, config.GetConnectionString does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the connection string is stored in env variable named `environment_variable_name`, then you can obtain it like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables("");
        var config = builder.Build();
        Services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options =>   
             options.UseSqlServer(config["environment_variable_name"]));
```

There were two problems here:

1. `GetConnectionString` will look for configuration key `ConnectionStrings:environment_variable_name`, not `environment_variable_name`. So either you have to change your env variable name to `ConnectionStrings:environment_variable_name` or use `config["environment_variable_name"]` to obtain the value.
2. The first argument to `AddEnvironmentVariables` is not a variable name, but a prefix. This means that if I had env variables named `my_application` and `my_connectionstring`, the following code will get them:

   ```
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   builder.AddEnvironmentVariables("my_");
   var config = builder.Build();
   var appname = config["application"];
   var connstr = config["connectionstring];
   ```

This is useful, because you don't get your configuration cluttered with every possible environment variable, only filter those that you know you will be using. Note however that the prefix is stripped when accessing the variables.

In your example, if you have env variable named `environment_variable_name`, and use `AddEnvironmentVariables("environment_variable_name");`, then you could access its value with `config[""]`.